# Changing rows of data frame to columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in following format.

```
    Drug A    4   5   4   3   2   4   3   4   4 
    Drug B    6   8   4   5   4   6   5   8   6
    Drug C    6   7   6   6   7   5   6   5   5
```

I want to convert it to following format without manually entering the value.
as by

```
pain = c(4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 6, 8, 4, 5, 4, 6, 5, 8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5)
 drug = c(rep("A",9), rep("B",9), rep("C",9))
 migraine = data.frame(pain,drug)

    pain drug
1     4    A
2     5    A
3     4    A
4     3    A
5     2    A
6     4    A
...
25    6    C
26    5    C
27    5    C
```

Is there a better method to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an ideal use case for Hadley Wickham's `reshape2` package. [Here's a tutorial](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html) that will show you what you need. The `melt` function should do nicely for your purposes, I think.

Comment: Thank!! saved my day.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Happy to help.